# Confused over solving a ODE system (opposite answer as shown by graphing)

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

my problem set has the question:

> Given $$A=\begin{bmatrix} -3 & -2 \\ -1 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$$ find the general solution to the homogeneous system of differential equations $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=A\vec{x}$.

---

So, I solved this by first finding eigenvalues of $-2,-5$, and then eigenvectors of $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}.$

However, upon graphing this as
[such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv7U3.png), the eigenvectors shown on the graph are flipped compared to the ones I found. Why is this? Where did I go wrong?

Update: I have this exact same issue when solving the same problem where $A=\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 4 \\ 5 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: The eigenspace for a particular eigenvalue doesn't care about the eigenvector's direction because the span handles negative scalar multiples too.

Comment: Oops they aren't negative. I meant they're flipped over the axis. Look at the graph you'll see what I mean. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

After further review, I messed up some simple arithmetic when calculating the eigenvectors! So, there is no issue, aside from the eigenvectors needing one of the terms multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: Hi, please add this as an edit to your question instead of an answer.

Comment: @bobeyt6 Why? I figured out the problem so I clicked the answer your own question button, because this is indeed the answer to my question. Sorry I am new to this site, was this the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: In that case, please accept your own answer by clicking the check mark so it will be formally resolved. Welcome to Math.SE btw.

Comment: @bobeyt6 yes I was going to but it is imposing a time limit until I can accept it :) I have to wait 22 more hours.